# Convert symbolic equations into integer sequence

Tags: r, math, symbolic-math, algebra

To avoid repeatedly waiting minutes for compilation of a c++ program, I'd like to detect certain equation forms within R and convert them into a sequence of integers, to be processed by some further function (which would be already compiled in the main piece of software). The equations in question are for the time being composed of only one unknown / parameter, some offset / scaling type manipulations, and some combination of log and exponential. A small example is as follows:

```
    #user defined list of equations
eqs <- c('2*log(1+exp(0+3*d))-2', '2*d+1')


#replace this next line with code to detect / arrange equation list into integers
inteqs <- data.frame(type=c(1L,0L),outeroffset = c(-2L,1L),
  inneroffset=c(0L,0L),outermultiply=c(2L,2L),innermultiply=c(3L,1L))

#transformation function within main program
tform <- function(d,type,outeroffset,inneroffset, outermultiply, innermultiply){
  if(type==0) return(outeroffset + outermultiply * (inneroffset + innermultiply *d))
  if(type==1) return(outeroffset + outermultiply * log(1+exp(inneroffset + innermultiply *d)))
}

for(d in c(-2,0,3.1)){ #arbitrary values of the unknown / parameter
  print(2*log(1+exp(0+3*d))-2) #true value eq1
  print(do.call(tform,c(d=d,inteqs[1,]))) #function returned value eq1
  print(2*d+1) #true value eq2
  print(do.call(tform,c(d=d,inteqs[2,])))#function returned value eq2
}
```

As stated in the example, I'd like some function to convert from an arbitrary equation of the form described, to an appropriate integer sequence.

Comment: This is not that simple. A proper implementation would require parsing the expressions and then encoding them as a sequence of *bytecodes* representing the basic functions such as `log`, `exp`, `*`, `+`, `-`, etc., as well as numeric constants. At runtime you should be able to *execute* the bytecodes in such a way that the result reproduces the evaluation of the original expression. Doable and interesting indeed, but a lot of work for sure.

Comment: Right i figured it's not so simple, but also thought there may be pre-existing functions that do something similar - I was impressed how well the Deriv package could simplify a similar list of equations, for instance.

Comment: 1) you may try to use e.g. `s <- parse(text = '2*d+1')[[1]]` to get the tree with operations and symbols (here `s[[1]]` is `+`, `s[[2]][[2]]` is 2 and `s[[2]][[3]]` is `d`). 2) If you have only limited number of equation types, you may provide a constructor function for the user, i.e. type0(offset, mult) and type1(ioffset, imult, ooffset, omult), which will create a data structure to be sent to C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely different approach: Use the user-provided formula to generate data points, and then fit a curve to the points to recover the parameters.  As a bonus, we can use AIC (or whatever measure you prefer) to identify which type of formula the user provided in the first place.

**Pros:** Robust to various ways of writing the same formula.  Scales up relatively easily to different types of formulas.  Code is more readable than the "tree-walking" alternative.

**Cons:** Seriously, this seems like major overkill.  Also has the potential to be a bit noisy (i.e., not 100% guaranteed to recover the correct formula).  Function may need some adjusting to use a different range of x values depending on which formula we're testing.  You also have to specify by hand which formula types allow which parameters.

```
# Function to figure out the parameters of a user-written formula.
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
fit.eqs = function(e) {
  # List the types of formulas we might encounter.
  formula.types = data.frame(
    type = 0:3,
    formula = c(
      "y ~ a * x + b",
      "y ~ a * log(1 + exp(c * x + d)) + b",
      "y ~ a * log(x + d) + b",
      "y ~ a * (exp(x) / log(1 + exp(x + d))) + b"
    ),
    outeroffset = 0,
    inneroffset = c(NA, 0, 0, 0),
    outermultiply = 1,
    innermultiply = c(NA, 1, NA, NA),
    aic = NA,
    stringsAsFactors = F
  )
  # Get some x values over a wide range, and compute the corresponding y
  # values.
  xs = seq(0.01, 10, 0.01)
  ys = eval(eval(substitute(substitute(e, list(d = xs)), list(e = as.quoted(e)[[1]]))))
  data.to.fit = data.frame(x = xs, y = ys + rnorm(length(ys), 0, min(diff(ys)) / 100))
  # Try to fit each formula to the data.
  for(i in 1:nrow(formula.types)) {
    start.params = list(a = 1, b = 0)
    if(!is.na(formula.types$innermultiply[i])) {
      start.params[["c"]] = 1
    }
    if(!is.na(formula.types$inneroffset[i])) {
      start.params[["d"]] = 0
    }
    fit = nls(as.formula(formula.types$formula[i]),
              data = data.to.fit,
              start = start.params,
              control = list(warnOnly = T))
    formula.types$outeroffset[i] = round(coef(fit)[["b"]])
    formula.types$outermultiply[i] = round(coef(fit)[["a"]])
    if(!is.na(formula.types$innermultiply[i])) {
      formula.types$innermultiply[i] = round(coef(fit)[["c"]])
    }
    if(!is.na(formula.types$inneroffset[i])) {
      formula.types$inneroffset[i] = round(coef(fit)[["d"]])
    }
    formula.types$aic[i] = AIC(fit)
  }
  # Return the values we found.
  return(formula.types %>%
           filter(aic == min(aic)) %>%
           mutate(inneroffset = coalesce(inneroffset, 0),
                  innermultiply = coalesce(innermultiply, 1)) %>%
           select(type, outeroffset, inneroffset, outermultiply, innermultiply))
}

# Equations for testing.
eqs <- c('2*log(1+exp(0+3*d))-2',
         '2*log(1+exp(3*d))-2',
         'log(1+exp(3*d+0))*2-2',
         '2*d+1',
         '(2*d)+1',
         '(1)+(2*d)',
         'log(1+d)*2')

# Parse the equations and produce the correct integers.
inteqs.fitted = do.call(
  "bind_rows",
  lapply(eqs, fit.eqs)
)
```

Comment: Nice. I switched out nls for a different optimization approach that still works when the system is not fully identified, I'll post the final result as a separate answer but accept this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach.  Not the most efficient or robust way, but it handles the equations given in your example, and is (as far as I've tested) robust to differences in order of operands and in use of parentheses.  It does *not* handle non-atomic values for offset (e.g., `d + -3`, as opposed to `d - 3`).

```
# This recursive function walks down the tree and extracts offsets/multipliers.
# The "e" argument contains the expression we want to parse.  The "l" argument
# specifies the current level we're trying to parse (outer offset -> outer
# multiplier -> type -> inner offset -> inner multiplier).  It returns a named
# list with the relevant values specified.
library(dplyr)
extract.integers = function(e, l) {

  # If we're done, no need to do anything else.
  if(l == "done") { return(list(type = 0)) }

  # Initialize the list of values we're going to return.
  values.to.return = list()

  # Based on the current level, which level will we explore next?
  next.level = "done"
  if(l == "outeroffset") { next.level = "outermultiply" }
  else if(l == "outermultiply") { next.level = "type" }
  else if(l == "type") { next.level = "inneroffset" }
  else if(l == "inneroffset") { next.level = "innermultiply" }

  # If we're finding an offset, determine its value by adding to (or
  # subtracting from) zero.  If we're finding a multiplier, determine its value
  # by multiplying by (or dividing into) one.
  default.arg = 0
  if(grepl("multiply", l)) {
    default.arg = 1
  }

  # If the expression does not involve an operation, we've hit the bottom of
  # the tree.
  if(!is.call(e)) {
    return(list())
  }
  # Otherwise, get the top-level operation.
  else {
    operation = e[[1]]
    log.equation = F
  }

  # If this is a log or parentheses, go straight down to the next level (and
  # set the equation type appropriately if this is a log).
  if(is.element(as.character(operation), c("log", "("))) {
    next.expression = e[[2]]
    if(as.character(operation) == "log") {
      log.equation = T
      if(is.numeric(next.expression[[2]])) {
        next.expression = next.expression[[3]]
      } else {
        next.expression = next.expression[[2]]
      }
      next.expression = next.expression[[2]]
    }
    else {
      next.level = l
    }
  }
  # Otherwise, figure out which argument has the actual value of the
  # offset/multiplier and which has the next expression we're going to parse.
  else {
    arg1 = e[[2]]
    arg2 = e[[3]]
    arg.with.value = arg1
    next.expression = arg2
    if(is.numeric(arg2)) {
      arg.with.value = arg2
      next.expression = arg1
    }
    # If the operation matches the level we're trying to identify, proceed.
    if((grepl("offset", l) & is.element(as.character(operation), c("+", "-"))) |
       (grepl("multiply", l) & is.element(as.character(operation), c("*", "/")))) {
      values.to.return[[l]] = eval(as.call(list(operation, default.arg, arg.with.value)))
    }
    # Otherwise, try the next level down.
    else {
      next.expression = e
    }
  }

  # Recursive call to get values "lower down" in the expression.  Fill in the
  # value of the equation type, if known.
  sub.values.to.return = extract.integers(next.expression, next.level)
  if(log.equation) {
    values.to.return[["type"]] = 1
  }

  # Collect all the values we know so far.  Order is important, because we want
  # to overwrite default/earlier values appropriately.
  return(c(list(type = 0,
                outeroffset = 0,
                inneroffset = 0,
                outermultiply = 1,
                innermultiply = 1),
           sub.values.to.return,
           values.to.return))

}
```

Test with the equations provided, and a few variations:

```
# Test equations.
eqs <- c('2*log(1+exp(0+3*d))-2',
         '2*log(1+exp(3*d))-2',
         'log(1+exp(3*d+0))*2-2',
         '2*d+1',
         '(2*d)+1',
         '(1)+(2*d)')
# Parse test equations.
inteqs = do.call(
  "bind_rows",
  lapply(
    eqs,
    function(x) {
      extract.integers(parse(text = x)[[1]], "outeroffset")
    }
  )
) %>%
  select(type, outeroffset, inneroffset, outermultiply, innermultiply)
# Check whether parses are correct.
for(d in c(-2, 0, 3.1)) { #arbitrary values of the unknown / parameter
  print(2*log(1+exp(0+3*d))-2) #true value eq1
  print(do.call(tform,c(d=d,inteqs[1,]))) #function returned value eq1
  print(2*d+1) #true value eq2
  print(do.call(tform,c(d=d,inteqs[4,])))#function returned value eq2
}
```

Comment: Definitely a helpful start. I'll have to work through it a bit to see how alternative log / exp arrangements, eg. `log(1+d)*2' or 'exp(d) / log(1+exp(d))' can be handled, currently type 1 equations are detected too liberally.

Comment: Yes, this method will definitely need non-trivial expansion to handle other equation types.  After I posted this, I had a thought about a completely different approach that would "scale up" more easily to other formulas.  It has its own problems, but might be worth checking out - I'll post it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the curve fitting approach A.S.K posted didn't work with unidentified systems (eg. y ~ a * (c * x + d) + b), I altered some elements, the full solution may be helpful so am posting here. This won't return the exact equation specified, but a comparable one.

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(mize)

types=0:3
fit.eqs = function(e) {
  # List the types of formulas we might encounter.
  formula.types = data.frame(
    type =types,
    formula = c(
      "y ~ a * x + b",
      "y ~ a * log(1 + exp(c * x + d)) + b",
      "y ~ a * exp(c * x + d) + b",
      "y ~ a * (exp(c * x + d) / (1 + exp(c * x + d))) + b"
    ),
    outeroffset = 0,
    inneroffset = c(NA, rep(0,length(types)-1)),
    outermultiply = 1,
    innermultiply = c(NA, rep(1,length(types)-1)),
    lsfit = NA,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
  # Get some x values over a wide range, and compute the corresponding y
  # values.
  x = c(seq(-2, 2, .1),seq(-10,10,.5),c(rnorm(10)))
  y = eval(eval(substitute(substitute(e, list(param = x)), list(e = as.quoted(e)[[1]]))))
  x <- x[abs(y) < 1e5]; 
  y <- y[abs(y) < 1e5]

  # Try to fit each formula to the data.
  for(i in 1:nrow(formula.types)) {
    start.params = list(a = 1.01, b = 0.01)
    if(!is.na(formula.types$innermultiply[i])) {
      start.params[["c"]] = 1.01
    }
    if(!is.na(formula.types$inneroffset[i])) {
      start.params[["d"]] = 0.01
    }

    ff <- function(pars){
      a=pars[1];b=pars[2];c=pars[3];d=pars[4]
      yest<- eval(parse(text=gsub('y ~','',as.character(formula.types$formula[i]),fixed=TRUE)))
      res <- (sum( ((y-yest)^2)/(abs(y)+.01)))
      if(is.na(res)) res <- 1e100
      return(res)
    }

    ffg <- function(pars){
      g=try(numDeriv::grad(ff,pars,method='simple',
        method.args=list(eps=1e-8,d=1e-10,r=2) 
      ),silent=TRUE)
      if(class(g)=='try-error') g <- rnorm(pars)
      if(any(is.na(g))) g[is.na(g)] <- rnorm(sum(is.na(g)))
      return(g)
    }

    fit = try(mize(par = unlist(start.params),
      fg = list(fn=ff,gr=ffg),
      max_iter=100,abs_tol=1e-3,rel_tol=1e-5,
      method='BFGS'))

    if(fit$f < .1 && fit$f > 1e-5) {
      message('close, ', round(fit$f,3))
      fit = try(mize(par = unlist(start.params), #if close, refine estimate
      fg = list(fn=ff,gr=ffg),
      max_iter=500,abs_tol=1e-5,rel_tol=1e-6,
      method='BFGS'))
    }

    if(class(fit)=='try-error') browser()
    formula.types$outeroffset[i] = fit$par[2] #round(coef(fit)[["b"]])
    formula.types$outermultiply[i] = fit$par[1] #round(coef(fit)[["a"]])
    if(!is.na(formula.types$innermultiply[i])) {
      formula.types$innermultiply[i] = fit$par[3] #round(coef(fit)[["c"]])
    }
    if(!is.na(formula.types$inneroffset[i])) {
      formula.types$inneroffset[i] = fit$par[4] #round(coef(fit)[["d"]])
    }
    formula.types$lsfit[i] = fit$f #AIC(fit)
  }
  # Return the values we found.
  print(formula.types)
  return(formula.types %>%
      filter(lsfit == min(lsfit)) %>%
      mutate(inneroffset = coalesce(inneroffset, 0),
        innermultiply = coalesce(innermultiply, 1)) %>%
      select(type, outeroffset, inneroffset, outermultiply, innermultiply,lsfit))
}

# Equations for testing.
eqs <- c('2*log(1+exp(0+3*param))-2',
  '2*log(1+(exp(3*param)))-2',
  '1.4 * (exp(3 * param + 8) / (1 + exp(3 * param + 8))) + .4',
  '2*param+1',
  '(2*param)+1',
  '(1)+(2*param)',
  'exp(1+param*1)*3',
  'param^3',
  'sqrt(exp((param^2)))'
  )

# Parse the equations and produce the correct integers.
inteqs.fitted = do.call(
  "bind_rows",
  lapply(eqs, fit.eqs)
)

round(inteqs.fitted,3)
```

Comment: Nice!  This does look more robust.  Useful reference; thank you.